# Grails injected Mail Service bean is null inside a controller

Tags: email, grails, intellij-idea

I am trying to use the following Grails Mail plugin: https://grails.org/plugin/mail

I've added the depedency in **BuildConfig.groovy**:

```
plugins {
 //mail plugin
        compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:1.0.7"
}
```

The I've configured it to use a specific email by adding the following code in **Config.groovy**:

```
grails {
    mail {
            host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            port = 465
            username = "-my email-"
            password = "-my password-"
            props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                     "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                     "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                     "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
            from = "no-reply@kunega.com"
        }
}
```

I have a controller where I declare the **mailService** so it should be injectd as a bean:

```
@Secured("permitAll")
class RegisterController {

    def mailService

    def springSecurityService

    @Transactional
    def registerAccount(UserCommand userCommand) {
        def model
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            model = [success: false, message: 'Log out to register a new account.']
            response.status = 400
        } else if (userCommand.validate()) {
            User u = userCommand.createUser()
            u.save(flush: true);
            Role role = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER")
            UserRole.create u, role, true

            def link = createLink(controller: 'register', action: 'activateAccount', params: [code: u.confirmCode])

            mailService.sendMail {
                async true
                to 'kunega@mailinator.com'
                html "<a href=" $ { link } ">Activate your account on Kunega</a>"
            }

            model = [success: true, message: 'An activation link has been sent to your email.']
            response.status = 201
        } else {
            model = [success: false, errors: userCommand.getErrors()]
            response.status = 400
        }
        render model as JSON
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the **sendMail** method it in the **registerAccount** method of the controller. However I get an error, which basically says that the mailService object is null. Here is the error message:

```
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [POST] /Kunega/register/createAccount
Cannot invoke method $() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method $() on null object
    at com.kunega.RegisterController$_$tt__registerAccount_closure2.doCall(RegisterController.groovy:32)
    at grails.plugin.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:53)
    at grails.plugin.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:59)
    at com.kunega.RegisterController.$tt__registerAccount(RegisterController.groovy:29)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And there is another strange thing that I should mention. I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate Edition, and here is a curios thing: 
[image]

If you notice inside the highlighted area with red, the IDE is showing that it can't recognize the arguments inside the closure that is passed to **sendEmail**.
I've never used this plugin before, so I just followed the steps in the docs, but apparently something is wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's easier to debug if you show line numbers in IDE (in this case in incomplete source code of RegisterController)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
html "<a href=" $ { link } ">Activate your account on Kunega</a>"
```

which I suppose should be either:

```
html "<a href=\""+ link + "\">Activate your account on Kunega</a>"
```

or

```
html "<a href=\"${ link }\">Activate your account on Kunega</a>"
```

otherwise you call a method `html` with params `"<a href="`, `$`, `{ link }` (closure that returns "link") and `">Activate your account on Kunega</a>"`.

Comment: That did the job. I couldn't figure it out by using the error/exception message.

Comment: The trick is, that you call the `mailService.sendMail` method with a closure. That closure gets executed against a specific context (by changing the `delegate` of the closure) hence the call stack looks weird.